# output of pretrained facenet model is [2, 512] instead of [1, 512]

Tags: pytorch, facenet

I am using facenet to extract facial features from set of frames in a video. Below is the code:

```
import torch
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1

resultlist = []
def ImgFeatures(image_path):
    mtcnn = MTCNN(keep_all=True).eval()
    model = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    cropped = mtcnn(image)
    result = model(cropped).detach()
    return result

resultlist.append(ImgFeatures(image_path)
troch.stack(resultlist)
```

I stack the output using `troch.stack(resultlist)`. This gave the following error, showing that there are few values that are of dimension [2, 512]

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/local/ASUAD/pgouripe/Workspace/MEnMaE/MEGNN/facenet_check.py",
> line 37, in 
> result = torch.stack(resultlist) RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1, 512] at entry 0 and [2, 512] at entry 54

I also notices the following warning when running facenet.

> I0000 00:00:1711242913.736970 1889714 gl_context_egl.cc:85] Successfully initialized EGL. Major : 1 Minor: 5
> I0000 00:00:1711242913.754006 1892985 gl_context.cc:357] GL version: 3.2 (OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 535.161.07), renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

I am unable to figure the cause for the issue, Can someone help with more clarity.

I have search for the specific issue and did not find any references.

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace.

Comment: @Ivan; I have edited the output. Please have a look. I figured out that the warnings are not related to the error.

Comment: If the error is cause by another portion of your code, then you need to provide the appropriate code sample.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, it was mtcnn that provided more than 1 outputs even though there was only 1 face image.